# Magento grid pagination issue

Tags: magento

I have a custom module. I added a grid into my admin panel page. Grid is loading fine. But pagination is not working. When i select an option from drop down, it redirects to the frontend. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You may miss `gridAction` in the controller. Add this code in your admin controller file.

```
public function gridAction() { 
     this->loadLayout(); 
     this->getResponse()->setBody( this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourmodule/adminhtml_yourmodule_grid')->toHtml() );
}
```